# Convert list into correct input for polyfit

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a polynomial to two lists.

The function is `pylab's` `polyfit`. The following works:

```
z4 = polyfit(randInput, y, 4)
```

The following breaks it:

```
z4 = polyfit(myInput, y, 4)
```

If

```
randInput = random.rand(6)
```

then

```
randInput = [ 0.02634194  0.70933754  0.99000924  0.53837119  0.61318163  0.89089385]
```

However, trying to make my own:

```
myInput = ['1', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26']
```

What kind of data structure is `randInput` and how do I convert  `myInput` to the same kind of data structure, so that `polyfit` works?

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting when you call the method?

Comment: Maybe because Python ```random``` does not have a `rand()` attribute. Or perhaps the invalid ```random.rand()``` code seems to have no relation to the file reading code.   -- down votes that is, not mine by the way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the question for clarity. Since there is an answer I would like to leave it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you need to convert each item in your file to `int` explicitly:

```
x = []
with open('test3.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        xs,ys = line.split(',',1)
        x.append(int(xs.rstrip()))
print x
```

`random.rand` is generating a list of `float` objects, but you're reading integers from your text file. It's hard to say for certain since you haven't included the actual error message you're getting, but the method will probably accept any numeric type (which would include `int` and `float`).